# How to import my own class into Cocoapods third party library?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm using Cocoapods to manage third party libraries, and I want to import my own class into a third party library, how can I do this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend modifying a third party library if you are using Cocoapods. Because I think your changes will be reverted if you upgrade your pod to another version. I would recommend that you make a Category of this library instead. Please refer to this documentation of Apple about Categories
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html